# Can't connect to server router failing

Tags: networking, router, vpn, ping

I have been trying to connect to my University VPN with this new router I have installed at home, it works for all websites except when I am trying to access the server hosting the vpn of my school.

this the info trace from traceroute and ping

```
Traceroute: bind: Can't assign requested address

ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
```

The Dns seems to be working as I get the same results when pinging the IP address of the server directly, and firewall is also disabled, I suspect it has something to do with the router and I have access to its internal configurations.

Any thoughts on where the problem might be ?

Comment: What firewall is disabled? If the router's, immediately enable it.

Comment: I did but that doesn't seem to solve the problem

Comment: To resolve your issue, contact your university's tech support, as it's likely a config issue on their end. The router's firewall, in and of itself, is not the issue, so re-enabling it would not solve the issue. When you disable a router's WAN side firewall, you expose it directly to WAN (a massive security issue and something that should never be done). Almost all consumer electronics are not intended to be directly connected to WAN without an intermediary firewall and most OSes do not have a default WAN profile set up by default to allow safely connecting w/o a router